Any way to tweet videos/audios in tweepy? (python)
I'm getting error when trying to tweet videos on tweepy. I'm using free tier version with all persmissions. My code was:


# V1 Twitter API Authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# V2 Twitter API Authentication
client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token,
    api_key,
    api_key_secret,
    access_token,
    access_token_secret,
    wait_on_rate_limit=True,
)

# Upload image to Twitter. Replace 'filename' your image filename.
media_id = api.chunked_upload(filename="Pledge.mp4",
                            media_category="tweet_video").media_id_string
print(media_id)

# Text to be Tweeted
text = "Hello Twitter!"

# Send Tweet with Text and media ID
client.create_tweet(text=text, media_ids=[media_id])
print("Tweeted!")

I saw it worked for images, but when running for .mp4, i got:
1843760094611189760
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\ai-agents\projects\final_try\twitterbot_karaoke_deploying\aaa\e.py", line 84, in <module>
    client.create_tweet(text=text, media_ids=[media_id])
  File "C:\Users\pablo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 835, in create_tweet
    return self._make_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pablo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 129, in _make_request
    response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\pablo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 96, in request
    raise BadRequest(response)
tweepy.errors.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
Your media IDs are invalid.

It seems like it got the media_id but got error in the last line

hi guys, how could I share a public URL for a audio/video file in python? (Free options preferably). Looking for some kind of library to do so, in that way i can share with others the resultant audio/video file

This posting on reddit might be having an impact on your efforts, https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/10rlzur/twitterdev_starting_february_9_we_will_no_longer/ I have tried several packages with no success on the free tier.
